# multiple math operators newcommand not working

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

I'm trying to create a \newcommand, on my system, called `\states` which takes two arguments. It should look like this (image below): 
[image]

But the angle brackets are not appearing when I try (MWE) :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\state}[2]{$\underline{#1}\langle#2\rangle$}
\newcommand{\statebf}[2]{$\underline{\mathbf{#1}}\langle#2\rangle$}

\begin{document}
 \state{A}{\xi}
 \statebf{A}{\xi}
\end{document}
```

I tried the same on an [online environment](https://latexbase.com/d/b332236c-6b80-4f7f-ad8b-87b0e0c33a9f) and it works. Any hints of what I am missing on my package  or a way to get around this would be very helpful

Comment: mahtbf is a typo, but besides it works. If it doesn't work for you, you should show your log-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your 4th line to

```
\newcommand{\statebf}[2]{$\underline{\mathbf{#1}}\langle\boldsymbol{#2}\rangle$}
```

[image: output from changed tex file]

Changing mathfb to mathbf corrects a typo; adding boldsymbol makes the Greek letter turn bold too. I don't see any problem with the angle braces.